# Duplicate key exception on merge statement in DB2

Tags: java, concurrency, db2, db2-luw

The problem: Everyday we get lots of parts that we want to add to our stock. We get messages over a queue that we read from (using 4 different servers). The queue always contains elements so the servers read as fast as they can. We want the servers to simply update the article if the article exits, and insert it if it doesn't.

Our first, naive solution was simply to select to see if the article existed, and if it didn't we wanted to insert. However since there was no row for us to lock we got problems with two servers doing the select at the same time, finding nothing, and then trying to insert. Of course one of them gave us a duplicate key exception.

So instead we looked to the merge statement. We made a merge statement that looked like this (simplified for clarity):

```
    MERGE INTO articles sr
    USING ( 
        VALUES (:PARAM_ARTICLE_NUMBER))
        AS v(ARTICLE_NUMBER)
    ON sr.ARTICLE_NUMBER = v.ARTICLE_NUMBER
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET 
        QUANTITY = QUANTITY + :PARAM_QUANTITY
                ARRIVED_DATE = CASE WHEN ARRIVED_DATE IS NULL
                THEN :PARAM_ARRIVED_DATE
                ELSE ARRIVED_DATE END
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (QUANTITY, ARRIVED_DATE)
        VALUES (:PARAM_QUANTITY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

However, for some reason we are still getting duplicate key problems. My believe is that even if the merge statement is atomic two merge statements can run concurrently and select at the same time.

Is there any way, short of locking the whole table, to make sure we only get one insert?

Comment: Hm. My equally naive first thought on this: Do the select. If found, do update. If **not** found -> forward to insert-queue. Have only **one** server (maybe with another as failover) handle the insert queue. This would then do the same logic you have now - only it can be sure that noone else is doing parallel inserts.

Comment: You would get the same problem, since 4 servers would select and find that it's missing. Then it would end up 4 times on the insert queue. In the end the one server would end up doing all of the work. And this would degrade performance so much that it's really a last resort, since this is a timecritical part of the system.

Comment: This would depend on your insert / update ratio i guess.

Comment: What DB2 platform/version?

Comment: What isolation level is your application using?

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a "special register", so shouldn't be a host variable.  It also means `ARRIVED_DATE` will never be null, so you shouldn't need the `CASE` either....  Although it begs the question of why you're using two different dates (potentially) during update and insert like that...

Comment: @IanBjorhovde might be right - you might be able to "fix" this by upping to RS.  However, I get the feeling `MERGE` wasn't intended to be used this way by multiple concurrent processes.  You also may be RBARing the process.  What about dumping everything to an unkeyed staging table and running the `MERGE` off that?  Your version of DB2 likely supports data-change-tables, so you should be able to do it from deleted rows...

Comment: @IanBjorhovde We are just using the standard CS  level. Might consider uping it.

Comment: @mustaccio we are using DB2 v10.1.0.2 with fixpack 2

Comment: :CURRENT_TIMESTAMP was a mistake when simplifying it for this post, I fixed it. Things are also inserted into the table from different sources so the case is required (some things are registered before they arrive, and we just want to update them when they arrive, others we need to registrer on arrival).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a similar situation running the `MERGE` with the Repeatable Read isolation level solved our problem. RS was insufficient, because it still allowed phantom rows, which is exactly the issue you are experiencing. You can simply add `WITH RR` at the end of the statement and try it out.

Our test suite runs with up to 1000 simultaneous connections and we don't see concurrency much affected by the RR isolation used for that particular statement only.

Answer (score 0):

Do the insert first, catch the duplicate key exception if thrown; then update instead.

Charles