# DB2 LUW merge statement concurrency

Tags: sql, merge, db2, db2-luw

I'd like to know how a *insert-if-not-exists* operation can be done efficiently in DB2 without causing unique constraint violations.

I tried using a `MERGE` statement in DB2 LUW but I am concerned about concurrency regarding duplicate inserts. I read in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n803.html) that changing the isolation level might help with these errors. According to a different stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34678150/412446) the `WITH RR` option *seems to work*, but I'd like to know for sure.

Will the `RR` isolation level guarantee that `MERGE` for *insert-if-not-exists* always succeeds without constraint violation errors? Is there maybe a weaker level that provides the same guarantee? And is a `MERGE` like

```
MERGE INTO some_table t
USING (VALUES(?)) vals(id)
ON t.id = vals.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT INTO some_table(id) VALUES(vals.id)
ELSE IGNORE
WITH RR
```

equivalent to a conditional insert with the same isolation level?

```
INSERT INTO some_table(id) VALUES(?)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM some_table 
  WHERE id = ? 
  WITH RR
)
```

Comment: Comment.  I always use the insert where not exists because it works on databases other than DB2.

Comment: @danny117 MERGE was added to the SQL2003 standard, if you're using a DB that doesn't support it...maybe it's time for an upgrade?